# Como posso dentro de uma classe que estende de BroadcastReceiver realizar alguma alteração na interface gráfica?

Tags: android, android-layout, broadcastreceiver

Tendo uma ActivityMain(herda de Activity) chama um broadcast, e então a classe Broadcast é iniciada. Porém quando realizada alguma ação nesse broadcast desejo alterar informações do textView que pertence a classe ActivityMain e faz parte de um adapter customizado(BaseAdapter).

Comment: Você poderia criar um outro `receiver` dentro da sua `Activity` que é notificado pelo primeiro `receiver` que você usou, passando todos os parâmetros que você precisa para alterar a interface.

Comment: @Wakim eu ja utilizo um receiver que eu instancio na propria activity.. mas queria saber se existe algum modo de fazer issu "separado", ou seja, o broadcast sendo uma classe a parte fora da activity

Comment: Sim, basta usar o padrão `Observer` (`Listener`) nessa classe. Tendo uma interface que a `Activity` ou outro classe implementa, para ser notificado pelo receiver. Você pode usar um `Handler` da `MainThread` para processar eventos. Mais detalhes em: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias formas de atualizar a `View` de uma `Activity` de uma classe externa, vou ilustrar duas que são de fácil implementação:

## 1. Usando o Design Pattern `Observer` (`Listener`)

#### Definição da interface Listener

```
public interface OnEventChangedListener {
    public void onEventChanged(/* Parametros */);
}
```

Essa interface será usada pelo `BroadcastReceiver` e implementada pela `Activity` para tratar a ocorrência do evento.

#### Definição do `BroadcastReceiver`

Se você está registrando ele em seu `AndroidManifest` e não criando e registrando programaticamente em sua `Activity`, o `OnEventChangedListener` precisa ser `static`, caso contrário poderá ser uma variável de instância e com um *setter* não estático.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static OnEventChangedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onConnectionChanged(/* Parametros */);
        }
    }

    public static void setOnOnEventChangedListener(OnEventChangedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    OnEventChangedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onConnectionChanged(/* Parametros */);
        }
    }

    public void setOnOnEventChangedListener(OnEventChangedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Em sua `Activity`, você precisa apenas registrar o `Listener`:

#### Definição da `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnEventChangedListener {

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Remover a referência para não causar um Leak de memória!
        MyBroadcastReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Restante do código de sua Activity

        // Registro do Listener
        MyBroadcastReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // É legal tirar a referência quando a Activity sair do topo do TaskStack.
        MyBroadcastReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Recolocando quando ela vier a ser o topo do TaskStack.
        MyBroadcastReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEventChanged(/* Parametros */) {
        // Tratamento do evento
    }
}
```

Se você cria e registra o `BroadcastReceiver` em sua `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnEventChangedListener {

    MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mItentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Remover a referência para não causar um Leak de memória!
        mReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Registro do BroadcastReceiver
        mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

        mReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(this);

        mItentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mItentFilter.addAction("SEU_ACTION");

        // Espera para registrar no onResume
        //registerReceiver(mReceiver, mItentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        // É legal tirar a referência quando a Activity sair do topo do TaskStack.
        MyBroadcastReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mItentFilter);
        // Recolocando quando ela vier a ser o topo do TaskStack.
        MyBroadcastReceiver.setOnOnEventChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

## 2, Usando um `Handler`

Nesse caso, iremos criar um `Handler` na `Main Thread`, que receberá mensagens do `BroadcastReceiver`, atualizando a `View`.

#### Definição da `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnEventChangedListener {

    Handler mHandler;
    MyBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mItentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(msg.what == CONSTANTE_ATUALIZAR_VIEW) {
                    Bundle data = msg.getData();

                    // Mensagem enviada pelo BroadcastReceiver.
                    // Será executada na MainThread.
                    // Atualizar a View com os parametros.
                }
            }
        };

        // Registro do BroadcastReceiver
        mReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

        mReceiver.setHandler(mHandler);

        mItentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        mItentFilter.addAction("SEU_ACTION");

        // Espera para registrar no onResume
        //registerReceiver(receiver, mItentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mItentFilter);
    }
}
```

Como lembrado pelo [Piovezan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/357/piovezan), deixamos para registrar no `onResume` da `Activity`, e removemos o registro no `onPause`. Para evitar consumir recursos desnecessários enquanto a `Activity` não estiver visível. É claro que pode ser uma decisão não fazer, talvez seja urgente o tratamento do evento mesmo com a `Activity` não visível.

#### Definição do `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(mHandler != null) {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(CONSTANTE_ATUALIZAR_VIEW);

            Bundle data = new Bundle();

            // Seta os parametros no Bundle

            msg.setData(data);

            // Envio a mensagem para o Handler na MainActivity
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }
}
```

O processo para o `BroadcastReceiver` registrado no `AndroidManifest` é análogo.

## Referências:

1. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: Muito boa resposta. Apenas sugiro chamar `registerReceiver()`/`unregisterReceiver()` nos métodos `onResume()`/`onPause()` (entre os quais a `Activity` está efetivamente ativa na tela) ao invés de `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()`.

Comment: Legal, @Piovezan, bem lembrado. Eu nunca tinha usado o registro programatico, sempre direto no `AndroidManifest`, vou acrescentar isso na resposta.

Comment: @Wakim eu ja tinha feita a primeira opção usando interface... e nao tinha dado certo pois nao fiz : public void setOnOnEventChangedListener(OnEventChangedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    } o restante tinha feito igualzinho... agora com esse metodo resolveu meu problema, mas ainda nao consegui entender pq precisa dele...

Comment: @PedroRangel, atualizei a resposta, permitindo retirar a referência da `Activity` no `BroadcastReceiver` quando não é mais necessário. Isso é bom pra evitar Leak de memória. Já que a `Activity` é um objeto muito pesado.

Comment: @Wakim muito bom.. eu ja utilizo ela.. mas eu coloco no onStart() e no onStop()...

Comment: @PedroRangel, pode ser, mas o `onPause` ocorre quando você abre um `Dialog` ou `DialogFragment` ou uma nova `Activity` (Quando uma nova `Window` é criada e tornada visível). Ai é só testar para ver qual é o melhor nesse caso. Estou sem o ambiente no momento, quando eu tiver um tempo posso acrescentar essa informação

Comment: @Wakim de boas...eu dei uma olhada no ciclo de vida da activity vou utilizar no onPause mesmo, muito obrigado.