# Usando Postgres no Android com AsyncTask

Tags: android, postgresql

Estou querendo conectar minha app em android direto com o banco que está em um servidor. Fiz a conexão em uma AsyncTask, segue o codigo.

```
public class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Connection> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String endereco = "jdbc:postgres://192.168.1.36/sics";
    private final String usuario = "postgres";
    private final String senha = "postdba";

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    public ConnectionTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Aguarde...",
                "Tentando realizar conexão com o banco de dados!", true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Connection doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(endereco, usuario, senha);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("CONEXAO", "NAO CONECTADO " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Connection result) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Até ai está tudo sem erro, porém da erro na minha DAO. Segue meu método listar abaixo.

```
public List<Categoria> listarCategoria(Context context) {
    List<Categoria> lista = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
    /*Cursor c = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "select * from categorias", null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        Categoria categoria = fill(c);
        lista.add(categoria);
    }
    return lista;*/
    Connection conn = new ConnectionTask(context).execute();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * form categoria");

    return lista;

}
```

Está dando erro na linha

```
    Connection conn = new ConnectionTask(context).execute();
```

Segue um print com o erro

[image: Erro]

Muito Obrigado desde já! :)

Comment: Acho que está havendo um problema conceitual. Sua `ConnectionAsyncTask` é uma abstração para executar um processamento em segundo plano (`doInBackground`) em uma `Thread` separada, publicar progresso na `MainThread` (`onProgressUpdate`) e finalizar com a atualização da UI (`onPostExecute`). Logo quando executa o `execute` da sua `AsyncTask`, esta começando esse processo, e não bloqueando a `Thread` atual na espera pelo resultado. Para corrigir o problema você precisa notificar essa classe, que chama a `AsyncTask`, dentro do método `onPostExecute` com o parâmetro recebido.

Comment: Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Na verdade a própria idéia do celular se conectar diretamente ao banco remoto é um problema conceitual. Em vez disso ele deveria chamar um web service (REST por exemplo) de um servidor que, este sim, se conecta ao banco. Há bastante material sobre isso na rede.

Comment: A questão é que isso é meu projeto da facul, e o tempo ta muito, mas muito curto mesmo. Íamos fazer um web service, mas devido ao tempo decidimos conectar direto com o banco e se sobrar tempo faremos um WS.

Comment: Essa minha resposta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34073/6436) exemplifica dois modos de notificar a UI apartir de uma outra `Thread` ou Classe, ambas as soluções são válidas no seu caso, escolha a que melhor achar. Existem outras formas, mas limitei a apenas duas para não ficar muito extenso.

Comment: Viu amigo, esse ultimo codigo, o ip que voce usou é o ip local do computador onde esta o banco?

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo funcional para conectar-se no servidor com banco PostgreSQL usando a rede WiFi. Observação só funciona em Android acima de 3.0;

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Teste de Conexão" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Banco.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.util.Log;

public class Banco{
private Connection conn = null;
private Statement st;
private ResultSet rs;
String _senha, _usuario;
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

public void conectarPostgres(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.34:5432/sae0114user=postgres&password=teste");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

public void desconectarPostgres() {
    try { 
        conn.close(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}

public void sqlLogin(String usuario){ 
    try{
        String sql="SELECT * FROM saeusr where usuario='"+usuario+"'";
        st=conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            _senha = rs.getString("senha");
            _usuario = rs.getString("usuario");
        }
    } catch (Exception erro){
        Log.e("Postgres","Erro pesquisa: "+erro);
    }
}

public void sqlLista(){ 
    try{
        String sql="SELECT * FROM sae001 order by nom";
        st=conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            lista.add(rs.getString("nom"));
        }
    } catch (Exception erro){
        Log.e("Postgres","Erro pesquisa: "+erro);
    }
}

}
```

Main.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
Connection conn = null;
Button bt;
ProgressDialog dialog; 
Banco db = new Banco();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bt.setEnabled(false);

            TextView textoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textoView.setText("");

            new EfetuandoTeste().execute("SUPERVISOR");             
        }
    });
}

class EfetuandoTeste extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    String texto;

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        db.conectarPostgres();
        db.sqlLogin(params[0]);
        db.desconectarPostgres();
        if (db._senha!=null){
            texto = db._senha;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Cria a caixa de dialogo em quanto faz a conexão          
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Atualizando...");
        dialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

        dialog.dismiss();
        bt.setEnabled(true);
        TextView textoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textoView.setText(" - " + texto + " - ");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```